# Ribbon chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart, sankey-diagram

I search in R implementation (may be html widget on java script) a stacked bar chart in ribbon style, which allows you to see the rating change for each category in the dynamics.

It's look like ribbon chart in power bi desktop
[image]

Search rseek.org gave no results.

Comment: Could you use something like a StreamGraph? https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/155-interactive-streamgraph-change-offset/

Comment: it's not quite what I need because the position of the ribbon irrespective of its width in any month will be the same as other tapes . Thus, in this example it is impossible to trace the changes in the rating position. Seen just what a ribbon of shrinking/expanding . (a beautiful chart at the link, sorry)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229164/r-connect-bar-graphs-with-lines-filled-in-with-matching-bar-color and https://stackoverflow.com/q/70837348/7941188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find your answers with ggalluvial package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html

[image: Alluvial Chart with Stratum (image qouted from above link)]

Answer (score 4):

First off: Not a fan of that ribbon-styled stacked bar chart at all; while colourful and stylish, it's difficult to synthesise the relevant information. But that's just my opinion.

You could try building a similar plot in `ggplot2` using `geom_ribbon`. See below for a minimal example:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
one <- sample(5:15, 10);
two <- rev(one);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    x = rep(1:10, 2),
    y = c(one, two),
    l = c(one - 1, two - 1),
    h = c(one + 1, two + 1),
    id = rep(c("one", "two"), each = 10));


require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = l, ymax = h, fill = id), alpha = 0.4) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"));
```

[image]

If you need interactivity, you could wrap it inside `plotly::ggplotly`.

Comment: It's not quite what i need because in this plot two ribbon overlap instead stack. General idea of nedded plot is: 1. Enables to see overall sum of month (stack result) 2. Enables to see size of each group in month (stack result) 3. Enables to see rating and it changes (ribbon result)

Comment: @Edvardoss Well, if I were you, I would pre-calculate the upper/lower limits, ensuring that they don't overlap; then use `geom_ribbon` to plot. It's a work-around, but will give you a lot of flexibility. My example is just meant to get you started. I don't think there exists anything ready-made. R plots are generally more data-scientific, and less info-graphic.

Answer (score 4):

Using [ggsankey](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey) package.

In the following you can make use of `smooth` argument `geom_sankey_bump` to control the look/feel of the chart as in ribbon chart of Power BI.

```r
df <- data.frame (model  = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
                  
                  Year = c(2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018),
                  sales = c(450,678,456,344,984,456,234,244,655,789,234,567,234,567,232,900,1005,1900,450,345,567,235,456,345,144,333,555,777,111,444,222,223,445,776,331,788,980,1003,456,434))
          

#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
library(ggsankey)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year,
               node = model,
               fill = model,
               value = sales)) +
  geom_sankey_bump(space = 0, type = "alluvial", color = "transparent", smooth = 15) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "A", alpha = .8) +
  theme_sankey_bump(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Sales ($ ths)",
       fill = "Model",
       color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Sales per model per year")
```

[image]

---

On suggestion in comments, I tried replicating some of the features of power BI chart.

```r
# Prepare some data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  occupation = rep(c("Clerical", "Management", "Manual", "Professional", "Skilled"), 12),
  Month = factor(rep(month.abb, 5), levels = month.abb, ordered = TRUE),
  Sales = sample(200:1000, 60, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(Max = sum(Sales)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Max = max(Sales)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month,
               node = occupation,
               fill = occupation,
               value = Sales)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Month, y = Max/1.2),
           alpha = 0.5,
           fill = 'grey',
           width = 0.4) +
  geom_sankey_bump(space = 15, 
                   type = "alluvial", 
                   color = "transparent", 
                   smooth = 8,
                   alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Sales ($ ths)",
       fill = "Occupation",
       color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  labs(title = "Sales per occupation per month")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: for future readers, if you use `geom_col(aes(x = Month, y = Sales),...)`, this will come slightly closer to the desired look